# Убрать внешние ссылки с сайта Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как убрать ссылки с сайта Wordpress на форумы Worpdess и другие служебные сайты?

```html
<li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg"><a class="ab-item" href="https://pl.wordpress.org/">WordPress.org</a>  </li>
  <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation"><a class="ab-item" href="https://codex.wordpress.org/">Dokumentacja</a>  </li>
  <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums"><a class="ab-item" href="https://pl.forums.wordpress.org/">Forum pomocy</a>  </li>
  <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback"><a class="ab-item" href="https://pl.forums.wordpress.org/forum/prosby-i-informacje-zwrotne">Uwagi</a>  </li></ul></div>  </li>
```

Comment: Где именно эти сылки? В админке или в теме?

Comment: Зачем вам убирать ссылки из admin bar? Полагаю, что некие SEO-идеи )) Роботы не видят admin bar.

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ. Я только что заметил что они есть когда только я залогинен в админку. Поэтому все нормально. Спасибо.